# How are the year and month folders added to the uploads directory?

Tags: uploads

How are the month (and year) folders automatically added to the uploads directory? The plugin that I am writing keeps track of the folders in uploads and I want to be able to add the new folder(s) each month as they are created. Is there a filter or action related to his process?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I understand the process:

The [`wp_upload_dir()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1.1/src/wp-includes/functions.php#L1686) function is the main *control room* for the upload folder creation process and the [`wp_mkdir_p()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1.1/src/wp-includes/functions.php#L1458) function is the helpful assistant.

Everytime `wp_upload_dir()` is called, it's actually running a `file_exists()` check on the current upload folder, through the [`wp_mkdir_p()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1.1/src/wp-includes/functions.php#L1458) function.
If the folder doesn't exists it's created with `mkdir()`, but not `$wp_filesystem->mkdir()` as one would expect.

The `wp_upload_dir()` function checks if the `uploads_use_yearmonth_folders` option is set. In that case the *year/month* folders are created, by [default](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1.1/src/wp-includes/functions.php#L1798), from the current time of `current_time( 'mysql' )`:

```
// ... cut ...

if ( get_option( 'uploads_use_yearmonth_folders' ) ) {
    // Generate the yearly and monthly dirs
    if ( !$time )
         $time = current_time( 'mysql' );
    $y = substr( $time, 0, 4 );
    $m = substr( $time, 5, 2 );
    $subdir = "/$y/$m";
}

$dir .= $subdir;
$url .= $subdir;

// ... cut ...

// Make sure we have an uploads directory.
if ( ! wp_mkdir_p( $uploads['path'] ) ) {

// ... cut ...
```

where `$uploads['path']` is assigned to `$dir`.

The `wp_upload_dir()` function is called within the [`_wp_handle_upload()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1.1/src/wp-admin/includes/file.php#L186) function that's implicitly applied during uploads. We also note that the `media_handle_{upload,sideload}()` functions are wrappers for the `wp_handle_{upload,sideload}()` functions, that are again wrappers for the `_wp_handle_upload()` function.

So I wonder if you might want to hook into these upload processes, using for example the `wp_handle_upload` filter within the `_wp_handle_upload()` function:

```
/**
 * Hook into the upload/sideload processes and check out the upload path.
 */

add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload', function( $args, $action )
{
    if( isset( $args['file'] ) && file_exists( $args['file'] ) )
    {
        // Upload path of the new file:
        $path = dirname( $args['file'] )

        // ... do stuff here ...
    }            
    return $args;
}, 99, 2 );
```

where `$args['file']` contains the local path of the uploaded file and `$action` can be *'upload'* or *'sideload'*.

Comment: This is a great answer!